# how to implement external sinusoidal commutation using encoder feedback in BLAC motor?

Tags: servo, pmsm, commutation, sinusoidal

I have a linear permanent magnet synchronous motor with sinusoidal back-EMF and a sinusoidal driver with current operation which takes two reference sine waves with a 120-degree phase difference, insert them in a current loop, and produces the three phase inputs of the motor.

However, the commutation is external and I need to use encoder feedback to perform it in the controller and find two input sine waves of the driver. Could you please give me some tips on how can I implement sinusoidal commutation or a straightforward reference?

I found some papers, but they explained the current loop section which is done in the driver.